# JNLP Application not running when parameters are passed

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I've got an application which was converted from an applet to a stand-alone application.

The application consists of a JNLP file which contains a string as an argument and a jar containing a main method (and additional resources). The main method is called through the JNLP.

Working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        xmlParams = new String(
                base64Decoder
                        .decodeBuffer("/*Base 64 encoded XML here*/"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AppletSignatura applet = new AppletSignatura();
    applet.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    applet.init();
}
```

Not working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xmlParams = args[0];
    AppletSignatura applet = new AppletSignatura();
    applet.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    applet.init();
}
```

As shown in the code samples, it works only when the string xmlParams (it's static) is set beforehand, but not when it's passed as an argument to the main method. Why is that so?

Here's the JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/portafirmes/applets/" href="output.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>NotAnymoreAnApplet</title>
    <vendor>Me</vendor>
</information>
<resources>
    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
    <jar href="signer-applet.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="jackson-core-asl-1.9.0.jar"  download="eager"/>
    <jar href="jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.0.jar"  download="eager"/>
</resources>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<application-desc main-class="es.gematic.AppletSignatura">
    <argument>*ARGUMENT IN HERE*</argument>
<update check="background"/>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I haven't copied any Base64 String because they're long as ****, but they're properly encoded.

Comment: Is the `<update>` tag interfering? it seems to be at the incorrect scope for `<application-desc>`? Mind you this is only based on reading the [JNLP file syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html)/

Comment: Hey @Petesh! Thanks for your time. You're absolutely right, the update tag was not placed properly. Nevertheless, putting it outside of the ``<application-desc>`` tag didn't solve anything, neither did removing it or changing the "check" value to timeout or always, as the documentation states.

Comment: @Petesh, got to solve it! :) It was a NumberFormatException from a parameter which was being sent through the B64 XML! Thanks for your effort!!